# Php floatval get correct values

Tags: php, type-conversion, decimal

I need to get the float of a string. But am facing problem with 0 decimal values i.e -

```
floatval("10000.01") gives 10000.01
```

but

```
floatval("10000.00") is giving 10000
```

I need the later value as 10000.00 too. What am I missing?

Comment: refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1):

Try to use *number_format()* function instead for the same,

```
$numberValue = "10000.00";
$numberString = number_format($numberValue, 2);
```

Hope this will work fine.

Thanks.

Comment: This is converting it to 10,000. I don't need the commas('), just a simple plain floating number.